# systemd-resolved as mDNS responder

Tags: systemd, systemd-resolved, mdns

I'm creating a custom distribution where I need a DNS responder. I'm already using systemd so I would like to use systemd-resolved to manage mDNS (the device should announce itself as capable of a couple of services); I'm not sure whether or not this is possible, but the [systemd-resolved documentation pages](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html#:%7E:text=systemd%2Dresolved%20is%20a%20system,and%20MulticastDNS%20resolver%20and%20responder.) reports

> systemd-resolved is a system service that provides network name resolution to local applications. It implements [...] MulticastDNS resolver and responder.

I already added set `MulticastDNS=yes` in the configuration file, as well as under the `[Network]` section of the interfaces where I want mDNS to be enabled (I can verify that with `systemd-resolve --status eth0`).

However, I'm not able to understand how to configure the available services to be announces, as it was done with avahi by adding them in `/etc/avahi/services`.

Are there any other configuration file for systemd-resolved? Is this not possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The capability of using mDNS should be enabled in the */etc/systemd/resolved.conf* file, in the `[Resolve]` section, by setting `MulticastDNS=yes`. Moreover, it should be enabled in the `[Network]` section of each interface configuration file (the one for `systemd-network`) by setting `MulticastDNS=yes`.

The status of the `MulticastDNS` setting can be verified with:

```
~# systemd-resolve --status
Global
           Protocols: +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
    resolv.conf mode: uplink
Fallback DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com 8.8.8.8#dns.google 1.0.0.1#cloudflare-dns.com 8.8.4.4#dns.google 2606:4700:4700::1111#cloudflare-dns.com 2001:4860:4860::8888#dns.google 2606:4700:4700::1001#cloudflare-dns.com
                      2001:4860:4860::8844#dns.google

Link 2 (eth0)
Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6 mDNS/IPv4 mDNS/IPv6
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (enp1s0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

For each interface, `+mDNS` means that MulticastDNS is enabled in that interface. `Global` refers to the `systemd-resolved` global configuration.

Services can be configured by creating /service/.dnssd files with the following format:

```
[Service]
Name=%H
Type=_http._tcp
Port=80
TxtText=path=/stats/index.html t=temperature_sensor
```

see https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.dnssd.html for more informations.

Configuration files can be saved in:

- */etc/systemd/dnssd*
- */run/systemd/dnssd*
- */usr/lib/systemd/dnssd*

Comment: Can you give example of dnssd for sftp, ssh, smb broadcast ?

Comment: worked for me by only specifying multicast in global congig of resolved, after `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved`. `nsswitch.conf` is not updated but resolution seems to work, perhaps silently done by `systemd-resolved`.